# Executing python as root no module named

Tags: python, unix, root, sudo, python-import

Since I need to create a raw socket inside my python code, I need to run it as root.
When I do that I found out that my imported modules are no longer supported somehow:

```
`No module named foo`
```

(I used to run my scripts as `sh myScript.sh option1` where my python `script.py` is called from within `myScript.sh`).

Now I try: `sudo fullPathName/myScript.py` and I also included in its beginning

```
#!/usr/bin/python and make it executable by chmod +x myScript.py
```

still having the no `No module named foo` issue.

Comment: Where is `script.py`? Does your non-root user have `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set?

Comment: `/bin/python` is probably the wrong path for most systems.

Comment: actually my script.py is in some directory of my own. My non-root has environment variable set PYTHONPATH.
@FatalError: sorry I am using "/usr/bin/python" and I checked that python executable is there

Comment: Then you probably need it to be set when you run the script as root, as well.

Comment: Please use virtualenv to install external libraries, so you can maintain the packages and modules in better manner: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/ (virtualenv works for root too, doesn't need PYTHONPATH, please use it to avoid installing modules and packages directly to system folders)

Comment: @Mikko but `sudo` is not used for installation here.

Comment: How can I do that please, (Need it to be set when I run the script as root):
apart from my ~/.bashrc is there an equivalent for me when I run scripts as root for example ?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Does not matter

Answer (score 3):

You need to preserve `PYTHONPATH` when running commands with `sudo`. `sudo` can be configured to retain certain environment variables via the `sudoers` file.

So you can run `visudo` (as root) and add something like this:

```
Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
```

Then save the changes.